# How to init NSObject<protocol> pointer so it responds to delegate SEL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have such thing in my class definition:

```
NSObject<SomeProtocol> *dataDelegate;
```

I have custom `-(id)init` method in which I should init this `NSObject`. How do I do it if I want it to respond selectors from `SomeProtocol`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a class declared to implement `SomeProtocol`, then you'd just do:

```
@interface SomeClass:NSObject <SomeProtocol>
.... etc ....
```

And in the implementation:

```
dataDelegate = [SomeClass new]; // or alloc/init
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an instance of a class that implements the protocol.